# cannot find symbol BR in android data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-studio

I want to use Android Data Binding and has configured according to the official document.

the error message is :
error: cannot find symbol import net.juude.droidviews.BR;

the top level `build.gradle` file is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and the build.gradle file in app module is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.juude.droidviews"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22 
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    retrolambda {
        println("JAVA_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"))
        println("JAVA7_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME"))
        println("JAVA8_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME"))
        javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ptr-lib-debug')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile files('libs/droidmocks.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
}
```

the layout file is

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type=" net.juude.droidviews.databinding.User" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.mName}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_sex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.sex}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

the fragment is

```
package net.juude.droidviews.databinding;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import net.juude.droidviews.BR;
import net.juude.droidviews.R;

/**
 * Created by juude on 15-6-9.
 */
public class DataBindingFragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewDataBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_data_binding, container, false);
        //dataBinding.setVariable(BR.)
        User user = new User();
        user.setSex("男");
        user.setName("Juude");
        dataBinding.setVariable(BR.user, user);
        return dataBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

since I did not get syntax error in Android Studio， I can assume that the Android Studio can recognize the BR class;

But when I compile the project, It tells me that 
`error:cannot find symbol class BR`.

so I want to know what should I do to make it generate the right BR.java file?

Comment: Please post a SSCCE: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @d33tah Soryy, I have modified the question, maybe this will be ok

Comment: You can at least see the actual error in View->Tool Windows->Gradle Console. There will probably be an exception there that you can google.

Comment: check your room database related file, because of that class gradle build get failed, and will not get idea actually. issue is in room classes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a problem caused by android-apt plugin. It ignores the provided dependency that data binding plugin adds.

https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue/38/android-apt-breaks-brand-new-data-binding#comment-18504545

You can work around it by adding:
`apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc0` to your gradle file.

Comment: This was fixed in `android-apt` as of 1.6

Comment: I am still getting an error: `Error:Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc1.`

Comment: Igor, looks like u forgot to install latest Android sdk's support maven repository

Comment: @yigit : Where to add mentioned dependency mean which gradle?

Comment: changing
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
to
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7' fixed my error.

Comment: Is this still the correct way to fix this on Android Studio 3.0.1?

Comment: If none of the above works, like in my case, resolve all other compilation errors and this will go away.

Answer (score 37):

In case someone still has this problem. I solved this by invalidating the cache in Android Studio. And I'm using Android Studio 2 with API 23

[File > Invalidate Caches/Restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMTKF.png)

Comment: It still happens to me after issuing an invalidate and then restart.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works for me. I tried `Invalidate`, it doesn't work. Then I tried `Invalidate and Restart` and it works!

Comment: In my case it solved part of the problem but the import was not showing on Ctrl+Enter.
So I had to delete and write again 'BR.' 
Then Android Studio imported the class correctly.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Kotlin, try applying the following plugin to your app `build.gradle` file:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Clean your project and build it again. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: As of June 2020, this was the solution that worked for me. Seems strange that Google's docs on Data Binding are half assed and don't include crucial steps such as this.

Answer (score 9):

I find the cause of the problem in my case. I find in the import statements of my Data Object class contains:

```
import static android.databinding.tool.util.GenerationalClassUtil.ExtensionFilter.BR;
```

The problem gets solved after I removed that. Android Studio somehow resolved BR class wrongly for me.

Comment: Same issue here, my import was using the wrong class, I changed it to use `import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;` and it seemed to have resolved the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The Bindable annotation generates an entry in the BR class file during compilation. The BR class file will be generated in the module package.

```
@Bindable
   public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue too.  The problem was that I changed the class name and didn't update the values in the XML file.  This includes the variable names and where they are accessed in the xml file.

Comment: that is not the same issue

Comment: @Juude, it was the same error though.  I stumbled upon this post trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

For my case the issue was caused by

"error: variable MyVariable was already defined in class MyModel"

The annoying thing was Android Studio gradle build did not display this error at the bottom. I had to comment each databinding error > Rebuild Project until I reach the error. Lesson learnt was to scan through each error from bottom to top and notice anything you may have changed recently.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this to your **gradle.properties** file

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)

> you might get multiple errors reporting that the binding classes aren't found. The new data binding compiler prevents these errors by generating the binding classes before the managed compiler builds your app.

Answer (score 4):

I too got the same error message, but my root cause was different from what has been shared here.

In my case the issue was that after I resolved a merge conflict, I had by mistake left an extra `@Override` annotation on a method. Thus the JVM preprocessor failed and then also the data binding classes were not generated.

The irritating part for me was that I was unable to see any error message related to this, or it was hard to spot among all the other compiler errors. And Android Studio does not show the extra annotation as an error either. So in case someone else struggles with the same error, check that you don't haven an error in some annotation that prevents the APT preprocessor from kicking in.

Answer (score 3):

Just restarting Android Studio, without invalidating cache, did the trick for me (I'm using version 2.2.3).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Android Studio 2.3 release and your project configuration is as follow:

```
Gradle version: 3.3
Android plugin version:2.3.0
Compile sdk Version:23+
build tools Version:25+
```

All need to do is add

```
dataBinding{enabled=true}
```

to build.gradle, then sync gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

I had this plus 29 other errors suddenly crop up from one moment to the next. I tried clean, rebuild, invalidate caches / restart and no luck. In the end I removed changes I had made and redid them one by one. Found that I had `@Inject`ed a service in the wrong class. Once I removed that all 30 errors were gone. The errors gave no clue to what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to run `./gradlew clean build` in the project folder. It showed an error which android studio didn't.

Comment: Thanks, after doing that. Fixed by adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
```

Then sync project. Even if not works, invalidate cache and restart then clean & rebuild project.

Answer (score 2):

Generally **BR** class Generate automatically when you Rebuild your project and I have resolved the problem using this technique Still have issue you can try another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double-check the following steps:

1. GradleFile:

`dataBinding {enabled = true}`

2. Your class Model.

```
 import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable
 import androidx.databinding.Bindable
 import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR

 class User2(
     private var firstName: String,
     private var lastName: String
 ) : BaseObservable() {

     fun setFirstName(firstName: String) {
         this.firstName = firstName
         notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
     }

     @Bindable
     fun getFirstName(): String {
         return this.firstName
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dagger 2, the problem may be caused by dagger's components. Although two libraries are not related, in my case, fixing errors in Dagger reported in the compiler makes the BR class properly appear again.

Answer (score 1):

BR gets generated during compilation, `Build -> Rebuild project` should do the trick. But for me it failed with error:
`e:/home/xx/File.kt: (24, 46): Expecting an element` because on that line I had an incompleted `BR.`. Just commenting or adding anything after `.` and rebuilding solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the steps below,
1.Extend your class with BaseObservable class
2.Add @Bindable annotation to each getter methods.
3.Rebuild the project.
Now you'll be able to access BR

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried just running the project and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- In my case i haven't provided @PrimaryKey annotation on one of the entity and it was really difficult to find this error as in logs there are no clue to find it. so be sure to give your Entity a primary key, else this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your room database related file, because of that class gradle build get failed, and will not get idea actually. issue is in room classes.
what ever `androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR` error your getting those file is not generating because of room database class have some syntax error