# Databinding BR not showing all variable name

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I have implemented DataBinding with MVVM pattern, here is my `ViewModel` class.

```
public class MainViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private String data, data1;

    @Bindable
    public String getData1() {
        return data1;
    }

    public void setData1(String data1) {
        this.data1 = data1;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.data);
    }
}
```

now the problem is i can see `BR.data` there but not able to get `BR.data1`, how to use `notifyPropertyChanged()` for `data1` variable.

I have tried to clean the project, also tried with rebuild it but didn't help me.

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: can you post your `gradle` file ? and once try to `Invalidate Caches and Restart`.

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776466/cannot-find-symbol-br-in-android-data-binding

Comment: But that's about BR class, i don't have any error with BR class, it is just not showing all variable. Still let me try with `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

Comment: did you try using `BR.data1` to see if it compiles. (might be a studio bug)

Comment: @yigit yes that works, i guess its studio bug

Comment: Could you add an answer for this? The `BR` class makes a lot of trouble for me too. More than other resources created by `apt`.

Answer (score 9):

**Since AndroidX is here**

So, all you do need to change your import from

```
import your_package_name.BR
```

with below code

```
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR
```

Also, check your lifecycle library new version

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found few ways to solve this.

1) Try with `Invalidate caches and restart` in android studio.
2) As [yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859328/databinding-br-not-showing-all-variable-name#comment68936499_40859328) have mentioned, it is android studio bug, you can directly use variable instead of waiting for variable name to come as suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm what [@jee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883788/11502987) states works.
However if using androidx, the import statement will change to:

```
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR
```

Invalidate is not 100% needed. I just cleaned and rebuilt for my references to work again.

I am sure this is a Studio bug as [@yigit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859328/databinding-br-not-showing-all-variable-name/58028581#comment68936499_40859328) mentioned but there are no bug reports anywhere confirming this.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried following and it is working now:

1.
Change import of BR to
**import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;**

2.file->invalidate cahces/restart