# Cannot resolve BR in DataBinding android

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I implemented Databinding beforenever face such a problem. but, this time it is creating lot of trouble i can not import BR in my project. have a look at my gradle and code.

I tried all the possible solution from stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776466/cannot-find-symbol-br-in-android-data-binding).

```
package com.hcl.developer.telematics.Adapter;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import com.hcl.developer.telematics.Model.CarResponse;
 import com.hcl.developer.telematics.R;
 import com.hcl.developer.telematics.Utilities.CustomViewHolder;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by nirmal.ku on 9/7/2017.
 */

 public class CarDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>
  {

  private List<CarResponse> recentCarRequestList = new ArrayList<>();

public CarDetailsAdapter(List<CarResponse> recentCarRequestList) {
    this.recentCarRequestList = recentCarRequestList;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()), R.layout.history_list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = holder.getViewDataBinding();
    viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.car, recentCarRequestList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != recentCarRequestList ? recentCarRequestList.size() : 0);
}





     }
```

MyGradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hcl.developer.telematics"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
      dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


       }
```

My XML:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable
        name="car"
        type="com.hcl.developer.telematics.Model.CarResponse"
   />

</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_RegisterName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@={car.carRegistrationNumber}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstSecondLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.username}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_last_service"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.lastServiceDate}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="8sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/secondSecondLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/car_status"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.carStatus}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/car_type"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.carType}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thirdSecondLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_mileage"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.mileagePerLiter}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_trip"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@={car.totalTrip}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

then my model class:

```
  package com.hcl.developer.telematics.Model;

   import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
    import android.databinding.Bindable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CarResponse extends BaseObservable {

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.username);
}

         }
```

check my issue:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried import it manually?

Comment: you need to have `@Bindable public String getUsername();`. also read https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4

Comment: @RobertBanyai yes i tried

Comment: @Raghunandan i tried that too. but it didnt help me

Comment: if you build your project, dont you have any `BR.java` file under `build//generated/source/` folder?

Comment: @pskink no i checked it

Comment: @Nirmal yup BR is auto generated when you build the project. You need `Bindable` as suggested here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html if you username changes. Apart from that i don't see much wrong

Comment: Ok i will add it again @Raghunandan

Comment: @Nirmal i tried a sample similar to yours https://pastebin.com/44n0hRW9 and you see the sample code. It works

Comment: @Raghunandan can you post your full code please including xml and customviewholder class too

Comment: @Nirmal xml is the same as yours no changes and for view holder i followed this  https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4

Comment: @Raghunandan check my issue again. i have added image here. may i know which android studio version are you using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154423/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-nirmal).

Comment: @Raghunandan its android studio issue. thanks for your help guys. i tried in another machine exact this same code is working.