# error: package databinding does not exist and error: cannot find symbol BR

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

After working on many xml and activities, everything was just fine. Now this error comes. And the **worst thing is i can not find issue**.

```
error: package databinding does not exist
```

and this

```
error: cannot find symbol BR
```

Build stack trace only shows this.

Can some tell me what is way to find issue in project. Because `gradle` errors just showing `databinding` class build error.

As i searched lot. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934991/6891563) recommends to run with debug. When i build with debug then there are over 100k lines. How can i find exact issue line no?

> The issue was not directly link to Android Databinding. There were a
>   bug in the project (some variables not correctly setted)
>
> I would recommend to use gradle with **"--debug and --stacktrace"**
>   for more informations, it's helping a lot.

And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30793984/6891563) says to add some dependency. When i add this dependency

> It is a problem caused by android-apt plugin. It ignores the provided
>   dependency that data binding plugin adds.
>
> https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue/38/android-apt-breaks-brand-new-data-binding#comment-18504545
>
> You can work around it by adding: `apt
>   'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc0` to your gradle file.

I tried this but below error comes

```
Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

How to get rid of this issue. Can android tell exactly where is the problem?